# Вариантные делегаты в вариантных интерфейсах. Зачем нужны ключевые слова?

Tags: c#, .net, делегаты

Задал этот вопрос на англоязычной версии форума. Как обычно ответили так, что стало только хуже.
Наши отвечают дольше, но почти всегда понятно. Вроде разобрался с вариативностью по интерфейсам и делегатам. Но вопрос остался.

Возник вопрос о необходимости ключевых слов в вариантных делегатах, если их события находятся в вариантных интерфейсах. Вопрос касается только ключевых слов in и out для делегатов.

Как только мы создадим интерфейс с ключевым словом in, потребуется делегат с ключевым словом out, почему? В конце концов, delagate без ключевого слова out каким-то образом имеет ковариацию, но только для методов, а не экземпляров делегата, что означает, что я мог бы в любом случае поместить метод в событие, но не экземпляр делегата. Но мы не можем этого сделать.

```
namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            //Шаг 1
            B MyMethodReturnB()
            {
                return new B();
            }

            //Шаг 2
            MyClass<A> MyClassForA = new MyClass<A>();
            MyClassForA.MyEvent += MyMethodReturnB; //В MyClass<A>() вы можете поместить данные типа B с помощью метода MyMethodReturnB и без ключевого слова out в делегате MyDelegateReturn

            //Шаг 3
            MyDelegateReturn<B> MyDelegateReturnForB = new MyDelegateReturn<B>(MyMethodReturnB);
            //MyClassForA.MyEvent += MyDelegateReturnForB; //Но когда мы пытаемся передать данные типа B через переменную делегата без ключевого слова out, возникает ошибка, так вариативность работает в делегатах.
                                                           //Без ключевых слов in и out один делегат не может быть назначен другому делегату

            //Шаг 4
            IMyInterface<B> IMyInterfaceForB = MyClassForA; //Через интерфейс IMyInterface<B> без ключевого слова in вы не можете поместить MyClass<A>(), но если IMyInterface<B> с ключевым словом in, то мы можем

            //Шаг 5            
            //Как только мы создадим интерфейс с ключевым словом in, потребуется делегат с ключевым словом out, почему?
            //В конце концов, delagate без ключевого слова out каким-то образом имеет ковариацию, но только для методов, а не экземпляров делегата, что означает, что я мог бы в любом случае поместить метод в событие, но не экземпляр делегата. Но мы не можем этого сделать
        }
    }

    class A
    {

    }

    class B : A
    {

    }

    delegate T MyDelegateReturn</*out*/ T>(); //С ключевым словом out все работает

    interface IMyInterface<in T>
    {
        event MyDelegateReturn<T> MyEvent; //Ошибка из-за делегата без ключевого слова out
    }

    class MyClass<T> : IMyInterface<T>
    {
        public event MyDelegateReturn<T> MyEvent;
    }
}
```

Comment: Почему вам от [этого ответа](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66402759/12888024) "стало только хуже"?

Comment: «В конце концов, delagate без ключевого слова out каким-то образом имеет ковариацию» — что вы имеете в виду под термином «имеет ковариацию»?

Comment: aepot, ответом как обычно была ссылка с кучей выдержек из спецификаций, я на конкретный вопрос обычно ожидаю получить конкретный ответ.

Comment: VladD, я могу использовать вариативность в универсальных делегатах и без ключевых слов in и out, но только для методов - шаг 2. Но почему-то не в универсальных интерфейсах. https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/covariance-contravariance/variance-in-delegates, цитата: Если поддержка вариативности используется только для сопоставления сигнатур методов с типами делегатов, а ключевые слова in и out не используются, можно создать экземпляры делегатов с одинаковыми лямбда-выражениями или методами, но нельзя назначить один делегат другому.

Comment: Собственно в том и вопрос, почему я не могу использовать в универсальном вариантном интерфейсе универсальный вариантный делегат, в котором нет ключевых слов in и out, но только для назначения методов, а не самих делегатов. Ведь ключевые слова in и out в универсальных вариантных делегатах нужны только чтобы назначить один делегат другому.

Comment: Framework Design Guidelines, 3-е издание, 2020 г. Раздел 9.8 Covariance and Contravariance. Думаю, описание в этой книге всё прояснит.

Comment: https://metanit.com/sharp/tutorial/3.28.php

Comment: Alexander Petrov, думаю что это описание мало чем отличается от официальных спецификаций.

Comment: Александр Писковой, прочитал, уточните где там ответ на мой вопрос, касаемо интерфейса? Ключевые слова in и out в универсальных вариантных делегатах нужны только чтобы назначить один делегат другому. Для назначения методов вариативность есть и без ключевых слов in и out,что и видно по ссылке. Cмотрите шаг 2. Делегат был объявлен с ключевым словом out? Нет. Тем не менее это не помеха чтобы использовать его вариативность, но только при назначении метода. Почему я не могу сделать то же самое, но через интерфейс? Может кто-то ответить - не можешь, потому что ... аргументы ... и пример какой-то?

Comment: Нет, описание в упомянутой книге отличается и очень сильно.

Comment: Короче понятно, опять буду сам разбираться.

Comment: Дело в том, что эти тонкости, в которых вы пытаетесь разобраться, почти не нужны на практике. Просто ставишь `in` или `out` и всё. Компилятор или статический анализатор в IDE подскажут, что не так. Исправляешь - код работает. | Я когда-то разбирался с этим, вроде понял. Но со временем забылось. В прошлом году проштудировал FDG. И вот, спустя несколько месяцев, эти тонкости опять выветрились из головы. Потому что твёрдо запоминается лишь то, что реально нужно и часто применяется на практике.